# Popcorn-Time 3.2 beta installation

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I'm looking for answers but don't find any. I have ubuntu 14.04 and I had PT (Popcorn Time) that worked perfectly. After PT's site was down and relaunched with a new URL, I tried to install it and got the libudev problem. So I did:

```
sudo ln -sf libudev.so.1 libudev.so.0
```

The apk launched finally, but now after 2 seconds it gets blackened and doesn't respond. I tried to relaunch it (either with `./Popcorn-Time` or double-click it) and it just goes black again. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: So far I am aware their is no working popcorn time version for linux anymore. Not to mention that 3.2 is highly outdated.

Comment: My sister has Windows and there it works perfectly.
This is disappointing..

Comment: Last I read pt was facing a law suite and to my knowledge there is no working ppa for linux

Comment: I answered it here (http://askubuntu.com/questions/707425/installing-popcorn-time-on-bootable-usb-on-chromebook)

Comment: @riashat.rafat popcorn doesn't look like anymore! It's cotain only 3 files:
libffmpegsumo.so ; nw.pak ; Popcorn-Time

Comment: "Torrents Time lets anyone launch their own web version of Popcorn Time" http://venturebeat.com/2016/02/02/torrents-time-lets-anyone-launch-their-own-web-version-of-popcorn-time/. But it seems http://popcorntime-online.io/ working only for win/mac, because of lack of torrents-time version for linxu (?) :(