# Installing Popcorn time in Ubuntu running on Chromebook

Tags: usb, software-installation, chromebook

So I'm totally new at Ubuntu and just managed install it on a USB and boot on a Toshiba Chromebook 1. My first venture is to install Popcorn time on it, but since I've no experience, I'm having a hard time with it.

I downloaded the tar.gz from the Popcorn Time site, and extracted it using

```
tar -xf Popcorn-Time-*.tar.gz -C $$
```

And then

```
cd $$
```

To enter the Directory (I guess), but neither `./configure` nor  `sudo ./install`does much.

Help on how to install and run the thing would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to install an older I may help, as the latest build from popcorn-time.se has some compiling problem

Comment: I have no problem installing an older version. As long as it works and i get some idea how to do super basic stuff on ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Linux version from [here](https://popcorntime.ml/downloads/).

For simplicity of your installation, try to download it on your Download folder. Extract it.
You'll see a file named install.

[image]

Right click on it and go to Properties then Permission and allow executing file as a program.[image]

Now go to Files>Edit>Behavior and allow run executable text file when they are open.[image]

Now open a Terminal and drag the install file to the Terminal and hit Enter.
When prompt type: I agree and hit enter again.
[image]

Now Double Click on this popcorn-time and enjoy.
If doesn't start like the install file allow it to run as executable program by going to Properties>Preference.

[image]

Comment: It seems like it would work perfectly on a normal installation of Ubuntu, but i recieve the an Unexpected Error at 1: copying files. I expect this is because of it being being from a bootable USB with no partitioning or anything. An SD would probably be a better idea. Do you have any experience with this?

EDIT: it seems that if i run the Popcorn Time executable through the Terminal it runs smoothly.

Comment: Didn't get you.

Comment: The installation runs into an error. But running the executable straight through the terminal works all fine.

Comment: Enjoy your Popcorn time